# Having PHP syntax error

Tags: php, class, syntax

I am new to PHP & having syntax error on following two lines:

```
$title = (!empty( $utility->'title_' . $this->m_lang_key ) ? 
    $utility->'title_' . $this->m_lang_key : 
    $utility->title_1);
$slug = (!empty( $utility->'slug_' . $this->m_lang_key ) ? 
    $utility->'slug_' . $this->m_lang_key : 
    $utility->slug_1);
```

Can you please check how to resolve these errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Braces

```
$title = (!empty( $utility->{'title_' . $this->m_lang_key} )) ? 
    $utility->{'title_' . $this->m_lang_key} : 
    $utility->title_1;
$slug = (!empty( $utility->{'slug_' . $this->m_lang_key} )) ? 
    {$utility->'slug_' . $this->m_lang_key} : 
    $utility->slug_1;
```

Comment: Was `$utility->'title_'` added in 5.5? Previously you needed curly braces like `$utility->{'title_' . $this->m_lang_key}` for that to work.

Comment: You probably do need {} still, but the position of the `)` and is still a problem: duly added though